# How can I generate a signature file for an Android app and ensure proper execution during and after installation?

Tags: javascript, java, android

I'm trying to create a tool, but in the form of an Android app, I'd like to first create a tool that generates an Android app signature file, and then this file is used to sign the user's apps. I've read some links for this, but I'm not sure if it's proper programming practice. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There's already tools that create keystore files.  Why not just use them?

Comment: I want to make a tool for my personal use and I also want to learn the idea

Comment: In general you don't want to roll your own for anything dealing with cryptography.  The actual tools are security audited and looked over by experts for bugs and weaknesses.  Yours wouldn't be.